# ggplot dot plot adjust scale

Tags: r, ggplot2

My data looks like

```
junc                    old         new
X:65961303-65965481(+)  0.025672937 0.004911527
3:90310183-90313113(-)  0.098444488 0.002132802
6:51414210-51415178(-)  3.05E-05    4.37E-06
10:79322700-79323569(+) 0.33095695  0.302002001
4:122972516-122973173(+)    0.939167683 0.932705233
4:53030079-53033983(+)  0.000233548 0.00081976
13:56185646-56189613(-) 4.85E-10    9.43E-09
13:56189703-56197485(-) 4.82E-07    6.96E-09
11:98577839-98579023(-) 0.001854774 0.000894136
10:90615925-90621493(-) 0.000902529 2.84E-05
10:19614164-19624369(-) 4.38E-08    1.26E-06
```

I would like to plot a dot plot where my x axis is junc and y axis is value and each junc would ideally have two dots (new and old)

What I have tried so far:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
dat <- read.delim('~/plot.txt', sep = '\t', header = F)
head(dat)
colnames(dat) = c('junc', 'old', 'new')
head(dat)
mdat <- melt(dat)
head(mdat)

 p = ggplot(mdat, aes(x=mdat$junction, fill=mdat$variable)) + geom_dotplot(binpositions="all")
 p
```

Figure obtained: [image]

How do i adjust the scale and change the plot in such a way that I can visualize difference is old and new value for each junc.

[edit]
figure from AK88 suggestion 
[image]

EDIT:

```
> head(mdat)
                   junc variable        value
1   X:65961303-65965481(+)       old 2.567294e-02
2   3:90310183-90313113(-)       old 9.844449e-02
3   6:51414210-51415178(-)       old 3.048876e-05
4  10:79322700-79323569(+)       old 3.309569e-01
5 4:122972516-122973173(+)       old 9.391677e-01
6   4:53030079-53033983(+)       old 2.335478e-04
> 
>head(mlt)
junc variable value
1   X:65961303-65965481(+)  variable   old
2   3:90310183-90313113(-)  variable   old
3   6:51414210-51415178(-)  variable   old
4  10:79322700-79323569(+)  variable   old
5 4:122972516-122973173(+)  variable   old
6   4:53030079-53033983(+)  variable   old
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `melt` specify `id.vars = "junc"`:

```
mdat = melt(dat, id.vars = "junc")

ggplot(data = mdat, aes(x = junc, y = value, color = variable)) +
  geom_point(position = position_dodge(width = 0.2))
```

Comment: I have added figure in main question base don your suggestion

Comment: whoa, wait, can you post the `head` of your new melted data?

Comment: `junc variable value
1   X:65961303-65965481(+)  variable   old
2   3:90310183-90313113(-)  variable   old
3   6:51414210-51415178(-)  variable   old
4  10:79322700-79323569(+)  variable   old
5 4:122972516-122973173(+)  variable   old
6   4:53030079-53033983(+)  variable   old`

Comment: Can you post it into the body of your post? It is difficult to see the columns here.

Comment: posted head for both the variable

Comment: Sorry, I thought your `mdat` looked like the initial data that you posted in your post. See my updated code and let me know if it works.

Comment: posted new image with edit thanks, how do I account for number like `4.82E-07` which basically 10 power -4 on the scale ?

Comment: try this: `options(scipen=999)`

Comment: I  have accepted the answer as it addresses my main question would be great if i can understand how to factor in the scientific notation value, scipen would force not to use it right? from what i read

Comment: Yes, it basically removes the scientific notation for any output.

Comment: so it would be bascially 0.0 for anythign below that

Comment: Sorry, I was out ... no, it doesn't zero it out, it just gives you a normal value. Maybe this example will help: set `a = 3.05E-05` then see `a` then set `options(scipen=999)` and then observe `a` again.